# Term for the Fear of Fictional Characters

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

Is there any *phobia* or any other term for the fear of Fictional Characters of books, movies etc. (such as *Lord Voldemort*, *Dementors* of Harry Potter Series) ?

I am asking for a word which can be used to take the place of `xyz` in the following sentence :-

> *He is highly afraid of evil fictional characters, there's no doubt he is suffering from `xyz`.*

Comment: Would this person fear all fictional characters, or only the evil ones? It seems like the latter from your example, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @sumelic Evil ones.

Comment: [*Fictophobia*](https://meggardiner.wordpress.com/2007/01/21/fictophobia-baby-dont-fear-the-reader/)?

Comment: Now that I see this question after so much time, I find it so stupid! Time indeed changes people.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this list of phobias, there is not a specific phobia for *fear of fictional characters*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_phobias

The closest ones in this list are *coulrophobia* (fear of clowns), *sanguivoriphobia*  (fear of vampires), etc.

*Teratophobia* is somewhat close. [Wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teratophobia):

> An irrational fear of monsters.

The [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/phobia) of *phobia* is:

> An extreme or irrational fear of or aversion to something.

Phobias tend to be very specific. You've asked for a "Term for the Fear of Fictional Characters." "Fictional characters" is an all-encompassing term that includes every type of physical feature imaginable. I'm not sure there is one individual on Earth who truly has a phobia of *all* fictional characters. How could anyone have a phobic relationship with this guy?

[image: proof no one has a phobia of "fictional characters]

(...that is, unless you have [*dumasaphobia*.](http://www.dumasaphobia.com/about.php))

Phobias are not just simple fears, but [anxiety disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anxiety_disorder). Perhaps no dedicated phobia exists for *fear of evil fictional characters* because—at least while one is following the story—it is expected (and indeed rational) to fear the villains.

Comment: You could always invent a term - if you are good enough at Greek !

Comment: @mgb; you *could* – but is it wise? (In my opinion, there are more than enough *-phobia* words already in circulation – why not just say "fear of X" when that's what you mean!)

Comment: Santa Claus is (purportedly) a fictional character, and I'm pretty sure I've seen a term for fear of Santa Claus.

Answer (score 0):

Try "delusions" or "psychosis".

I agree with Kyle's answer, that there is not a specific *-phobia* word for this condition. I think the person would be suffering from *delusions* or some form of *psychosis* - that is they have a disconnect with reality as opposed to a specific phobia.